# BJT: Is \$ R_E || [\frac{R_s'}{\beta}+r_e] = (R_s'+ \beta r_e)|| \beta R_E\$?

Tags: transistors, bjt

**I am trying to find the effect of \$  C_E \$ on voltage gain.**

[image]

Circuit under AC conditions:

[image]

[image]

Doubt:

Is \$  R_E || [\frac{R_s'}{\beta}+r_e] = (R_s'+ \beta r_e)|| \beta R_E\$ ?

---

Reasoning:

Small signal model of BJT, **in general**, is given by:

[image]

To find \$  R_E \$ , we short-circuit the voltage signal source:

[image]

Effectively, the input portion of the circuit reduces to:

[image]

Therefore, it may be assumed that \$ i_b \$ flows through \$  R_E(1+\beta) \$.

---

Now, coming back to :

[image]

We have

\$ R_e= (R_s'+ \beta r_e)|| (\beta+1) R_E \$

\$ R_e= (R_s'+ \beta r_e)|| (\beta) R_E \$ (approx)

\$ =\frac{(R_s'+ \beta r_e)* (\beta) R_E}{(R_s'+ \beta r_e)+(\beta) R_E} \$

\$ = \frac{ (\frac{R_s'}{\beta}+  r_e)*(\beta) R_E}{ (\frac{R_s'}{\beta}+  r_e)+ R_E} \$

\$ = \beta [R_E|| (\frac{R_s'}{\beta}+  r_e)] \$

\$ \ne  [R_E|| (\frac{R_s'}{\beta}+  r_e)] \$

Why this discrepancy?

Comment: Well, in fact from the emitter point of view, the \$R_S\$ will be seen at the emitter as (beta +1) times smaller \$\frac{R_S}{\beta +1}\$

Comment: Is \$ R_E || [\frac{R_s'}{\beta}+r_e] = (R_s'+ \beta r_e)|| \beta R_E\$? No.  Compute Vb then Ib then Vc=β Ib Rc

Comment: Have a look at slide 40 in this APEC seminar http://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Downloads/PPTs/Chris%20Basso%20APEC%20seminar%202013.pdf

Comment: That slide is 1st order with Vs on base, his is 2nd order with RC to base so there is an input attenuation then a transimpedance gain.

Comment: It seems that both coupling capacitors (input and output) are considered short circuited here otherwise it becomes a third-order circuit. The equivalent small-signal circuit presented by the OP is only first-order.